# Laravel events & macros in testing

Tags: php, testing, laravel, laravel-4

When unit testing a Laravel project, macros are not registered and application events are not fired. For example, with the following file required from `app/start/globals.php`:

```
// app/helpers/nav.php

var_dump("nav.php loaded");

App::before(function($request) {
    var_dump("app::before called");

    HTML::macro('nav_link', function(..) { .. });
});

HTML::macro('nav_link', function(..) { .. });
```

Only the first var_dump will be printed. It seems that the `App::before` event is not called. Additionally, even outside the event, the `HTML::macro` call is not registered (a `BadMethodCallException` is thrown when it is attempted to be used). These work fine in normal usage.

The test case is fairly simple:

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    public function testBasicExample() {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the right scenario for adding helpers:

1. Originally I had them as PHP functions - meaning that the file they were in had to be `require_once`. As the app can be reloaded for each test (without clearing the internal included-files cache), these files weren't included on subsequent tests.
   a. Converted all appropriate functions to `HTML::macro`.
2. The `App::before` event is actually bound as a before filter on the router - which is not called by default (either remove the `App::before` or call `Route::enableFilters()` for each test).
3. Include the files that only contain macros from app/start/globals.php using `require`, not `require_once`. These need to be registered each app load (each test).